# How to close a form if a form is already opened in c#

Tags: c#, forms

I am trying to open a single form at once. If user tries to open another form while one form is already open it should not open it.

my code :

```
else if (instrument_name == "Micrometer")
{
    this.Hide();
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.ShowDialog();
    this.readclose()
}
```

here only if this form is not opened already then form 2 is opened.

the solution could be :

```
Form fc = Application.OpenForms["UpdateWindow"]; 

if (fc != null) 
   fc.Close(); 

fm.Show();
```

but I don't know where should I write this because if I put this `Form1_Load` then obviously it will not contain null even for the first time.

Should I put this in program file?

Comment: Did you try searching? Keep a reference to the form.

Comment: `ShowDialog` blocks.

Comment: sorry can you please elaborate@DanieA. White

Comment: Try to make Form2 global variable

Comment: Is there any control like button to open the second form

Comment: I still dont understand the problem. Please visit  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can create smth like 'form manager', which will monitor all opened forms. 
In situation when form is close the manager opens it, otherwise reopen it.

This solution is similar to your, but in this case all logic is concentrated in one place and easy to understand or maintenance it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it different ways. But one of it is to implement a singletone pattern. For that you have to modify your Form2 the following way:

```
    public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private static Form2 Instance;
    private Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static Form2 GetForm2Instance()
    {
        if(Instance==null) Instance = new Form2();
        return Instance;

    }

    public static void CloseOldForm2AndOpenNewForm2()
    {
        if (Instance != null) Instance.Close();
        Instance = new Form2();
        Instance.Show();
    }

    private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Instance = null;
    }
}
```

As you can see the Form2() is private. In order to load form you have to use the following code:

```
 //Case 1 if you porefer to use existing instance of the Form2
 Form2 myForm = Form2.GetForm2Instance();
 myForm.Show();


 //Case 2 if you prefer to close old one and create a new Form2
 Form2.CloseOldForm2AndOpenNewForm2()
```

Comment: It would be nice to have any response to my answer. Was it solve your problem? Yes, No, May be?